# Vue, Jest: how to mock element-ui components ? cannot find module element.css

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

My vue code calls `element-ui` modules:

```
// in main.js
import { Notification } from "element-ui";
```

At first, my test was throwing

> Cannot find module 'Element' from 'test.js'

so I mocked the module with

```
jest.mock('element-ui', () => ({
  Element: jest.fn(),
}))
```

However it still errors out with

> Cannot find module 'element-ui/lib/theme-default/element.css' from 'test.js'

and I don't know how to get passed this.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

---

If I import the element-ui components in my test.js:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/element-ui/lib/utils/dom.js:22:39)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/element-ui/lib/utils/popup/popup-manager.js:9:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/element-ui/lib/utils/popup/index.js:14:21)
```

(Jest 21.2, vue-test-utils 1.0.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped: https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-hackernews/

I now import all element-ui related components in the main.js, and I mock every method that calls one of its components:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // Mock this method that calls a Notification element-ui component.
    vm.notifyWarning = jest.fn();
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to register all Element-UI components before every test file.

jest.config.js (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array)

`module.exports = {
  ...,
  setupFiles: ['./jest/eachTest.js'],
  ...
}`

eachTest.js

`import Vue from 'vue'
import Element from 'element-ui'
Vue.use(Element, {})`